# Postman gets different response on same API endpoint vs browser

Tags: networking, postman

I've been trying to create an app which does some requests on Wizzair api, and found that there is this endpoint as `/Api/search/search`. While searching for flights in the browser this endpoint returns a list of flights based on the parameters provided as a json response. While accessing the same endpoint from postman and copying the same headers and body as the request I get a `428` response. That seems kinda odd, since the headers and body are exactly the same as the one in the `Newtork` tab in the Developer tools.

Here's a reference URL: https://wizzair.com/#/booking/select-flight/LTN/VIE/2022-07-23/2022-08-05/1/0/0/null

The added headers are:

```
Host: be.wizzair.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://wizzair.com/
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-RequestVerificationToken: <token>
Content-Length: 254
Origin: https://wizzair.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: <some_cookies>
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
TE: trailers
```

And the body is added as raw json:

```
{"isFlightChange":false,"flightList":[{"departureStation":"LTN","arrivalStation":"VIE","departureDate":"2022-07-24"},{"departureStation":"VIE","arrivalStation":"LTN","departureDate":"2022-08-05"}],"adultCount":1,"childCount":0,"infantCount":0,"wdc":true}
```

The response from postman is:

```
{"sec-cp-challenge": "true","provider":"crypto","branding_url_content":"/_sec/cp_challenge/crypto_message-3-7.htm","chlg_duration":30}
```

Could anyone explain to me why there is a different behavior on the browser vs postman on the exact same request and if possible replicate the proper response in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is still relevant.
But this one

```
{"sec-cp-challenge": "true","provider":"crypto","branding_url_content":"/_sec/cp_challenge/crypto_message-3-7.htm","chlg_duration":30}
enter code here
```

is a fingerprint of akamai bot protection. AFAIK it uses JS to tell real browser from scripted requests. It stores result in cookies, obfuscating it an every possible way. Good thing is that you can copy cookies from your browser session, and that way have several requests with meaningful results. After that akamai starts to try to change cookies again, and you'll have to start all over.